# Exception during test execution: ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: INVALID_API_INPUT - Order is not Activated

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception

This is how we are activating the order in the test class

```
// update order status to activated
List<Order> lstOrderToUpdate = new List<Order>([SELECT Id,status,AccountId FROM Order WHERE Id = :lstOrders[0].Id  LIMIT 1]);
lstOrderToUpdate[0].status = 'Activated';
try{
    Update lstOrderToUpdate;
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.debug('Exception>>'+ex);
}
```

The test class works in Sandbox but fails with an error in the subject when trying to deploy the change set in production.

Here is the stack trace

> Stack Trace Class.ConnectApi.Order SummaryCreation.createOrderSummary:
> line 28, column 1

Exception message:

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: INVALID_API_INPUT - Order is not
> Activated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DML `Update lstOrderToUpdate;` is throwing some exceptions. This exception is not visible for you, because of `try-catch` block. It is not a best practice to have generic exception catching and really nothing to do with it (not handling this exception). This is resulting in "silent" failing, which is not allowing you to find what line is actually failing.

Remove `try-catch` block and you'll see a real exception that is preventing you to set `Status` of the `Order` as `Activated` in your test.